# Conditional Regular Expressions

Tags: python, regex, conditional-statements

I'm using Python and I want to use regular expressions to check if something "is part of an include list" but "is not part of an exclude list".

My *include list* is represented by a regex, for example:

```
And.*
```

Everything which starts with *And*.

Also the *exclude list* is represented by a regex, for example:

```
(?!Andrea)
```

Everything, but not the string *Andrea*. The *exclude list* is obviously a negation.

Using the two examples above, for example, I want to match everything which starts with *And* except for *Andrea*.

In the general case I have an *includeRegEx* and an *excludeRegEx*. I want to match everything which matchs *includeRegEx* but not matchs *excludeRegEx*. **Attention**: *excludeRegEx* is still in the negative form (as you can see in the example above), so it should be better to say: if something matches *includeRegEx*, I check if it also matches *excludeRegEx*, if it does, the match is satisfied. **Is it possible to represent this in a single regular expression?**

I think Conditional Regular Expressions could be the solution but I'm not really sure of that.

I'd like to see a working example in Python.

Thank you very much.

Comment: "Is it possible to represent this in a single regular expression?" maybe, if you want to get clever enough, but regexps are too clever already, why hurt the person who has to read your code (including yourself).

Comment: I'm forced to use a regex. I have a gui filter from which I generate the regex I pass to an external module who accepts only regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not put both in one regex?

```
And(?!rea$).*
```

Since the lookahead only "looks ahead" without consuming any characters, this works just fine (well, this is the whole point of lookaround, actually).

So, in Python:

```
if re.match(r"And(?!rea$).*", subject):
    # Successful match 
    # Note that re.match always anchor the match
    # to the start of the string.
else:
    # Match attempt failed
```

From the wording of your question, I'm not sure if you're starting with two already finished lists of "match/don't match" pairs. In that case, you could simply combine them automatically by concatenating the regexes. This works just as well but is uglier:

```
(?!Andrea$)And.*
```

In general, then:

```
(?!excludeRegex$)includeRegex
```

Comment: The first example you've done is not a general solution to the problem. It works only in my example. In the general case I have *includeRegEx* and *excludeRegEx*.

For your second example I can see that strings like

    AndreaXXX

doesn't match. I'd like them to match, instead (it starts with "And" but it is not "Andrea").

Comment: Well, that's what the second solution is for. I thought that abstracting from that would be trivial. Will edit to clarify.

Comment: It doesn't seem to me that *(?!excludeRegex)includeRegex* is the solution. It it was, also *(?!Andrea)And.** should work, but it doesn't, as I've showed in my previous comment.

Comment: OK, added an end-of-string anchor (`$`) to make this happen.

Comment: @Luca, forget about conditionals, this is the solution.  For maximum flexibility you can express the *include* conditions as lookaheads too.  Then just run them all together: `^(?=And)(?=.{6}$)(?!Andrea$)` -- "starts with `And`, six characters long, not `Andrea`"

Comment: Actually, I would use `r'And(?!rea\b).*'` instead. You want the word to end there, not the whole line.